# ORM Tools Vs Design Patterns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I hope this will not close by the SO community.

**My Questions are:**

1. Can we use Design patterns (i.e. Gang of Four (GoF) : [.NET Design Patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)) with the ORM tools such as entity framework ?
2. If my development path is with the entity framework,should I learn above mentioned design patterns thoroughly?
3. How can we use other design patterns with EF Code First (except repository pattern) ?

Please share your thoughts with me. :)

Comment: Sorry, but in your profile you say you have over 6 years of programming experience? And a "dozen" of certifications? How did you survive _without_ design patterns?

Comment: @chrisdennig You're quite wrong here.I know and I read the GOF design patterns book and all.And I used those patterns before I moved into the EF world.But now I don't feel I do use them that much with the EF (except the Repository Pattern).That's why I asked about what are the other patterns which we can use with EF ?

Comment: Allright, allright :) mea culpa.

Answer (score 3):

Ans to Q1--> In fact ORM framework itself uses various design patterns like unit-of-work, visitor/iterator, strategy. Using ORM and design patterns side-by-side is perfectly OK

Ans to Q2--> Definitely It should help; Design patterns will help you design robust/extensible application no matter which ORM you use.

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit about your answer for the 2nd question where how can we use other design patterns with EF (except repository pattern)?